# Keras "Set" identifier not learning as expected

Tags: neural-networks, keras, games

I am using Keras to make a "set" identifier for the card game "set": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(game)

Here is my script (some code may be unnecessary but was used during experimentation):

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D
from keras.layers import MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Activation
from keras.layers import Flatten
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import Dropout
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
from keras.optimizers import SGD
from keras.utils import to_categorical
from keras.layers.advanced_activations import LeakyReLU
from keras.regularizers import l2

import os
import glob
import shutil

import numpy as np
from keras.preprocessing.image import load_img, img_to_array
from keras.applications.imagenet_utils import preprocess_input

earlystop = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_acc', min_delta=0.001, patience=5,
                          verbose=1, mode='auto')

callbacks_list = [earlystop]

# opt = SGD(lr=0.01)

setIdentifier = Sequential()

setIdentifier.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape = (64, 64, 3), activation = 'relu'))

setIdentifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))

setIdentifier.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), input_shape = (64, 64, 3), activation = 'relu'))

# setIdentifier.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), input_shape = (64, 64, 3), activation = 'relu'))

setIdentifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))

setIdentifier.add(Flatten())

setIdentifier.add(Dense(units=256, activation = 'relu'))

setIdentifier.add(Dropout(rate=0.5))

setIdentifier.add(Dense(units = 2, activation = "softmax"))

setIdentifier.compile(optimizer = "adam", loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])

from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255,
                shear_range = 0.2, 
                zoom_range = 0.2, 
                horizontal_flip = True)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory('Data_Training', 
                                                target_size = (64, 64),
                                                batch_size = 32,
                                                class_mode = 'categorical')

test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory('Data_Testing',
                                            target_size = (64, 64),
                                            batch_size = 32,
                                            class_mode = 'categorical')

setIdentifier.fit_generator(training_set, 
                                steps_per_epoch = 486,
                                epochs = 50, 
                                validation_data = test_set,
                                validation_steps = 60,
                                callbacks = callbacks_list)

setIdentifier.save("setIdentifier.h5")
```

The file 'Data_Training' has a folder "notSet" and a folder "Set", and the file 'Data_Testing' likewise. There are two times as many "notSets" than "Sets" in each category.

No matter what I do, in both training and testing phases, the output is always notSet. I am not sure what is the cause for this.

I have tried a binary_classifier with the sigmoid activation function and final density layer with 1 node. I have tried changing activation functions and using leakyRelus.

I have double checked my training steps and test steps. I have 5184 sets + 2 * 5184 notSet = 15552 train images, which when divided by a batch size of 32 gets me 486 steps. I have 648 sets + 2 * 648 notSet = 60.75 >> rounded to 60 validation steps.

I am confused by what is going on with the neural network - why isn't anything approving and why is it labelling everything with one class?

For more info, here is the Github repo which includes the training images:
https://github.com/Keyan-Rhm/MLWithSet

Any help is appreciated!